# kubernetes volume claim pending with specific volume name

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

I'm trying to create a PersistentVolumeClaim giv it a specific volumeName to use.

I use this code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: zipkin  
  name: pvc-ciro
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: nfs-provisioner
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 0.1Gi
  volumeName: "demo"
```

If I remove volumeName the PVC is correctly bound otherways remain in pending status.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `volumeName` is a name of the `PersistentVolume` you want to use.

On [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) PVC can automatically create a PV that will bound to, or you can specify the name of it using `volumeName`.

pvc.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-ciro
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: standard
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 0.1Gi
  volumeName: demo
```

pv.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: standard
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
```

And the output will be:

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM              STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
demo   5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Bound    default/pvc-ciro   standard                13s
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME       STATUS   VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc-ciro   Bound    demo     5Gi        RWO            standard       8s
```

You can read more details in Kubernetes documentation regarding [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

Comment: `PVC can automatically create a PV that will bound to` - really? You probably misunderstood [dynamic volume provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/)

Comment: In GKE if you create PVC it will automatically create PV that it will be bounded to.
Maybe I should have stated that differently.

Comment: I use this link to quick install zipkin on kubernetes. https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-zipkin. In yaml PVC sets volumeName beacuse It used in container creation and can not be randomly generated

Comment: @Crou volume is bound but zipkin does not install, /var/lib/mysql path not found

Comment: @Crou no, PVC will not create PV under any circumstances (or cloud env). I like your answer (and would like to upvote it), but please don't confuse people by introducing misconception.With dynamic provisioning enabled, PVC is satisfied automatically (not only in GKE, same is true for Amazon EBS, ...). But it is not PV that creates it... PVC only create demand for PV